# Multisort with supersort plugin

Tags: sorting, plugin-supersort, sort

I have entries that I would like to sort by 2 fields. First I would like to sort (or group) all of the entries in alphabetical order by a category field (brand), and then within each grouped brand I would like to sort the entries by a number field ascending (size).

I can perform both sorts individually with the syntax below, but I’m having difficulty combining them for a multisort-like function.

```
 entries|supersort('sortAs', '{ brand.first.title }')
 entries|supersort('sortAs', '{ size }', SORT_NUMERIC)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to group the entries sorted by size using the `group` filter:

```
{% set entriesSorted = entries|supersort('sortAs', '{ size }', SORT_NUMERIC) %}
{% set entriesByBrand = entriesSorted|group('brand.first.title') %}
{% set entriesByBrand = entriesByBrand|supersort('ksort') %}

{% for brand, entriesInBrand in entriesByBrand %}
    {% for entry in entriesInBrand %}
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks that grouped my entries by brand and ordered them by size. Is there a way to have the grouped brands display alphabetically?

Comment: Try to add another Supersort filter using 'ksort' method @triplethreat23!